# Rails 5.2 Active Storage with Cocoon forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, image-uploading, cocoon-gem, rails-activestorage

I want to save some images to a model using a dynamic cocoon form with Active Storage to handle the files.

I have a farmer class that has many apples, the farmer can add multiple images for each of the different kinds of apples through the farmer form.

```
class Farmer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apples, inverse_of: :farmer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apples, allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many_attached :apple_images
end
```

Inside the Farmer Controller I have:

```
class Farmer < ApplicationController


  def update
    @farmer = Farmer.find(params[:farmer_id])

    if @farmer.valid?
      @farmer.update!(farmer_params)
      redirect_to edit_farmer_path(farmer_id: @farmer.id)
    else
      ...
      ...
    end
  end

  private
  def farmer_params
    params.require(:farmer).permit(
      :farmer_name,
      apples_attributes: [
        :id,
        :color,
        :size,
        :_destroy
      ])
  end
end
```

my view I just added this to my cocoon fields

```
<div class="form-field">
  <%= f.label :apple_images, "Please upload apple images" %>
  <%= f.file_field :apple_images, multiple: true, data: { validates: {required: {}} } %>
</div>
```

Now cocoon will save the apple attributes using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call once the farmer object is saved. This is all working just fine until I tried adding the `apple_images` to the form.

Reading up on the Active Storage readme I see it suggests you should attach the files right after the item has been saved.

You can read the [readme here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage)

but in short if you want a single image in the controller do this:

```
#inside an update method
Current.user.avatar.attach(params.require(:avatar))
```

or if you want multiple images:

```
def create
  message = Message.create! params.require(:message).permit(:title, :content)
  message.images.attach(params[:message][:images])
  redirect_to message
end
```

This seems fairly simple when the image is directly on the model I am saving within the controller.

At first, I thought it may be just as easy as adding apple_images to the params like so:

```
  def farmer_params
    params.require(:farmer).permit(
      :farmer_name,
      apples_attributes: [
        :id,
        :color,
        :size,
        :apple_images,
        :_destroy
      ])
  end
```

but this will return an error:

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError - unknown attribute 'apple_images' for Apple.:
```

I am thinking about using an after_save callback on the apple model to attach the images after the apple object is updated / created. Although I am not sure how to achieve this either.

Feeling a little lost, any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated

*EDIT*

This is what the params look like at the time of update:

```
 <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch",
   "farmer"=>{"farmer_name"=>"billy the farmer", "apples_attributes"=>
     {"0"=>{"color"=>"Green", 
            "size"=>"A", 
            "apple_images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9e8aa93168 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/n7/65r5561n44q0w4bdnmw42l880000gn/T/RackMultipart20171211-87415-1m2w7gh.png>, @original_filename="Screen Shot 2017-12-07 at 09.13.28.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"farmer[apples_attributes][0][apple_images][]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2017-12-07 at 09.13.28.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, 
                             #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9e8aa93118 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/n7/65r5561n44q0w4bdnmw42l880000gn/T/RackMultipart20171211-87415-1gdbax2.jpeg>, @original_filename="WhatsApp Image 2017-12-06 at 1.23.35 PM.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"farmer[apples_attributes][0][apple_images][]\"; filename=\"WhatsApp Image 2017-12-06 at 1.23.35 PM.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], 
      "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"4"}}}, 
     "commit"=>"Next", 
     "controller"=>"farmer/produce", 
     "action"=>"update", 
     "farmer_id"=>"3"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: have a look in your log and see what params/field-names actually come through... edit your question and add them there.

Comment: Hi @TarynEast I have added the params. you will notice the `apple images` will move along with the rest of the apple params that will be saved through the farmer `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. ActiveStorage wants the images attached to the objects post saving I believe, ActiveStorage sets up polymorphic tables. I was wondering If I could pass the apple images to the Apple class outside of the apple attributes so that we could set up a after_save callback to attach the images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `apple_images` from the `farmer_params` (because it is not  a known attribute of `Apple`). But removing that will make sure the images are not saved. This is however, how it is intended to work (a bit weird imho).

If you check the documentation they explicitly ignore the `images` attribute and set it separately:

```
message = Message.create! params.require(:message).permit(:title, :content)
message.images.attach(params[:message][:images])
```

I am not entirely sure how you should solve this in a nested form setting. You could iterate over all apples in the params and try to set the `apple_images` but that seems very error-prone (how do you match a new apple without id to the one that is saved?).

You could try adding a method as follows (and keep the `apple_images` in the permitted params):

```
def apple_images=(images)
  self.apple_images.attach(images)
end
```

But not sure if that works before the `apple` is saved.

Comment: Thanks @nathanvda, I have moved the uploading of the images from cocoon to another step so we can add them directly to the object. What we discovered is that ActiveStorage is using some sort of anonymous polymorphic table to save the images, so the instance of the object needs to be saved so we have access to the ID, so you would need to do it in some after_save callback on the model. The only way I could see this working is if Cocoon had access to the object to pass in attributes for accepted nested attributes and then some way to define a model level callback? Thanks again though!

Comment: Sounds very reasonable. I frankly in general do the same: only add attachments to already existing items (i am a big fan of dropzonejs).

Answer (score 1):

Add `apple_images` as the key to a hash with an empty array, like this:

```
 params.require(:farmer).permit(
  :farmer_name,
  { apple_images: [] },
  apples_attributes: [
    :id,
    :color,
    :size,
    :_destroy
  ])
```

This is because when you upload multiple images at once, they're sent in params as an array.