# How to upload file in nested form using ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem, rails-activestorage

- I have `Project` that has many `Tasks`.
- Each `Task` can have an image uploaded using ActiveStorage.

In my Project new view I have dynamically created nested forms (via Cocoon) to create new tasks and file_field to upload an image per task. When the form is submitted I create a new Project along with new tasks from `project_params` in my Project controller. But how can I use ActiveStorage to attach each tasks' image after the Project is created?

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Nested form view

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :tasks do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Project controller

```
class ProjectController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.save
    ...
    # How should I attach task images here?
  end
end
```

I can access individual images within params:

```
"tasks_attributes": {
  "0": { "image": ... },
  "1": { "image": ... }
}
```

One way is to loop through each `@project.tasks` and call `.attach` on them with image from the params above in the same order. But that seems error prone since params doesn't give me task ID to match with the saved task, so I worry I won't be always attaching the image to the right task. If some of the tasks didn't save to db due to being invalid, the 1-to-1 matching breaks down making this approach even more brittle.

Is there a better way?

**Edit**

For some reason it's working now. I couldn't tell whether I changed something or it's the original code...

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752390/rails-5-2-active-storage-with-cocoon-forms

Comment: Thanks for the link. The author seems to had the same issue although he didn't actually resolve it and instead went to a different route by only upload image to an already saved nested object. I hope to find a solution to my problem as it will simplify the UI for my users.

Comment: For some reason I can upload files with the code I have as is. Not sure why it wasn't working before... maybe I changed something I wasn't aware of 

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the :id attribute under tasks_attributes in your Project Controller.  Literally just ran into that myself!